# Use ActionScript 3.0 to write Windows 8 app?

Tags: actionscript-3, windows-8, flash-builder

Is there a way to write Windows 8 app using Adobe Flash Builder ?
If I have a swf file, can I turn it into Windows 8 app ?

What are things that will stop working ? what will still be working ?

Comment: Do you have the original source, if so you can make an AIR project and export an installer for Windows I can give details.

Comment: Yes, I have the source code, do you mean Windows 8 app is a normal exe file after all ?

Comment: You can't use Adobe AIR yet with Windows 8 (the Metro side, at any rate). Last I heard from Adobe, this would be something included in AIR SDK 3.6 at the latest. 3.5 is currently in beta testing phases so it probably won't come in that release. EDIT: I take that last line back. Apparently I am a month behind the times and 3.5 is already out.

Comment: Sorry Samir I misunderstood I thought you meant just on the desktop side, I don't believe there's any way to run plugins in the Metro UI side of things.  I'm not privy on the latest that @Apocalyptic0n3 is talking about and tried doing a bit of searching but haven't come up with anything to get flash running within the metro UI, my best guess would be you create a launcher in the Metro UI that then launches the AIR program (which would just be an EXE) and deal with setting up the full screen chrome-less window in AIR.